# Call Set.contains without requiring comparison constraint

Tags: optimization, f#

In F#, `Seq.contains` requires only `equality` on the inner type. `Set.contains`, on the other hand, also requires `comparison`.

I want to make a function that efficiently checks if an item is contained in a `seq<'a>`. This `seq<'a>` could be a `Set<'a>`, in which case I'd like to use the more efficient `Set.contains`.

I have tried this:

```ml
let setOptimizedContains item (xs: seq<'a>) =
    match xs with
    | :? Set<'a> as x -> x.Contains item
    | _ -> Seq.contains item xs
```

However, that function now requires `comparison` on `'a`.

**Is there any way I can accomplish this without requiring `comparison` like this?**

A sufficiently optimized reflection-based approach (requiring compiled delegates, I assume) could be acceptable, but I don't know enough about reflection to optimize it sufficiently in this case (specifically, I haven't found a way to compile a delegate without ending up with the `comparison` constraint). For example, here is a *somewhat* optimized reflection-based approach (not compiled) with poor performance for non-Set cases:

```ml
let private tryGetOptimizedContainsMethod =
    let d = Dictionary()

    fun (t: Type) ->
        match d.TryGetValue t with
        | true, method -> method
        | false, _ ->
            lock
                d
                (fun () ->
                    match d.TryGetValue t with
                    | true, method -> method
                    | false, _ ->
                        let method =
                            if
                                t.IsGenericType
                                && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typeof<Set<_>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                            then
                                t.GetMethod("Contains") |> ValueSome
                            else
                                ValueNone

                        d[t] <- method
                        method
                )

let setOptimizedContains (item: 'a) (xs: seq<'a>) =
    match tryGetOptimizedContainsMethod (xs.GetType()) with
    | ValueSome method -> method.Invoke(xs, [| item |]) :?> bool
    | ValueNone -> Seq.contains item xs
```

```
|    Method |    N |  Impl |         Mean |      Error |     StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD |   Gen0 | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
|---------- |----- |------ |-------------:|-----------:|-----------:|------:|--------:|-------:|----------:|------------:|
|   Default |   10 | Array |     38.61 ns |   0.296 ns |   0.231 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 | 0.0019 |      32 B |        1.00 |
| Optimized |   10 | Array |    232.47 ns |   4.100 ns |   3.835 ns |  5.99 |    0.09 | 0.0305 |     512 B |       16.00 |
|           |      |       |              |            |            |       |         |        |           |             |
|   Default |   10 |   Set |    160.08 ns |   1.574 ns |   1.472 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 | 0.0429 |     720 B |        1.00 |
| Optimized |   10 |   Set |     48.22 ns |   0.392 ns |   0.367 ns |  0.30 |    0.00 | 0.0048 |      80 B |        0.11 |
|           |      |       |              |            |            |       |         |        |           |             |
|   Default | 1000 | Array |  2,779.40 ns |  54.438 ns |  74.516 ns |  1.00 |    0.00 |      - |      32 B |        1.00 |
| Optimized | 1000 | Array | 20,255.82 ns | 110.821 ns | 103.662 ns |  7.27 |    0.21 | 2.8687 |   48032 B |    1,501.00 |
|           |      |       |              |            |            |       |         |        |           |             |
|   Default | 1000 |   Set | 13,696.04 ns | 107.530 ns | 100.583 ns | 1.000 |    0.00 | 3.5858 |   60120 B |       1.000 |
| Optimized | 1000 |   Set |     62.47 ns |   0.420 ns |   0.372 ns | 0.005 |    0.00 | 0.0048 |      80 B |       0.001 |
```

Comment: Are you sure `Seq.contains` doesn't do the same optimization already?

Comment: It doesn't: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/5f59fa1d357cd10cae7124840fcdd01aa8aea170/src/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L680C33-L689

Comment: A hacky way around this could be to wrap `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SetModule.Contains()` with a function in a C# assembly and call that one from F#. I'm assuming `comparison` is checked by the F# compiler and this indirection would prevent that check from happening.

Comment: My guess is that Set requires comparison in order to build and traverse the internal tree in which the data is stored and achieve O(log n) time as opposed to O(n) for Seq.

Comment: @RolandAndrag Yes, I have no issue with Set requiring comparison in and of itself. I'd just like to avoid surfacing that requirement for the optimized `Seq.contains` function.

Comment: Sorry @cmeeren, I clearly read your question too quickly!

Answer (score 1):

### Static solution

If you know the type of the sequence at compile-time, you can use member overloads to handle this instead of downcasting:

```ml
type SetOptimized =

    static member Contains(xs : seq<'a>, item : 'a) =
        Seq.contains item xs

    static member Contains(xs : Set<'a>, item : 'a) =
        Set.contains item xs
```

Example usage:

```ml
[<NoComparison>]
type MyType = Wrap of int

// a sequence of non-comparable items
let mySeq = [Wrap 1; Wrap 2; Wrap 3]
SetOptimized.Contains(mySeq, Wrap 2) |> printfn "%A"

// a set of comparable items
let mySet = set [1; 2; 3]
SetOptimized.Contains(mySet, 2) |> printfn "%A"
```

---

### Dynamic solution

Otherwise, here's a reflection-based version:

```ml
let genericSetType = typeof<Set<_>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition()

let setOptimizedContains item xs =
    let xsType = xs.GetType()
    if xsType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = genericSetType then
        xsType.GetMethod("Contains").Invoke(xs, [|item|]) :?> bool
    else
        Seq.contains item xs
```

Example usage:

```ml
let mySeq = [Wrap 1; Wrap 2; Wrap 3]
setOptimizedContains (Wrap 2) mySeq |> printfn "%A"

let myRuntimeSet : seq<_> = set [1; 2; 3]
setOptimizedContains 2 myRuntimeSet  |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed my current workaround. It requires duplicating the relevant parts of the public API of my library (having `Set` overloads in addition to `seq`), and it only works if it's statically known that the sequence is a `Set` (an assumption I generally cannot make, though it's better than nothing). Since it's only a workaround, I won't mark this as accepted, but it can still be helpful to others.

Comment: I've updated this answer to include a reflection-based solution as well. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @BrianBerns The dynamic solution may possibly be improved by comparing against `typedefof<Set<_>>`, saving one method call.

Comment: @BrianBerns Thanks for the reflection approach, but I have already tried that. It's faster for sets, but I benchmarked it also for `int array`. Even when further optimized (specifically, caching `MethodInfo` based on the `Type` returned from `xs.GetType()`), this is then 5-10x slower and allocates a heck of a lot (Seq.contains allocates 32B regardless of N, whereas this allocates 512B for 10 items and 48kB for 1000 items). I have updated my question with what I've tried and performance results.